# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

In `Activity A` i am playing a song, and now moving to `Activity B` here again a button to play a different song

Now i have to check if `Activity A's` song `already playing` when i am on Activity B i have to show message to user already playing song on Activity A, if user not playing song on Activity A then user can start playing song in `Activity B`

**ActivityB.java:-**

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(ActivityA.mPlayer!=null && ActivityA.mPlayer.isPlaying()) // getting exception
    {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Already playing song on Activity A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else 
    {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
      }
    }
});
```

Now when i am `getting` this `Exception`: like i have started `playing song` in Activity `A`, and now moving to Activity `B`, here i `tapped on play` button - it **shows** me message `"Already playing song on Activity A"` then i decided to go back to activity A and i tapped on pause now i am not playing song in Activity A and again i moved to Activity B (here when i do tap on `Play` button getting `IllegalStateException`) at this line:

`if(ActivityA.mPlayer!=null && ActivityA.mPlayer.isPlaying())`

```
**`Logcat:`**

11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101): Process: com.example.audio, PID: 7101
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at com.example.audio.ActivityB$1.onClick(ActivityB.java:43)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18431)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
11-01 12:39:38.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Dont use ActivityA music player object in ActivityB just pass the boolean value in the intetn from ActivityA to B.

Comment: @kalyanpvs you mean i have to use Intent here

Comment: +1, yes. It should be the correct way to do that

Comment: @Sophie yes..Use intent for checking playing in ActivityA..@Blaze Tama posted it as answer check like that

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to do it this way in the `ActivityA` :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("isPlaying", mPlayer.isPlaying);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the `ActivityB's` `onCreate` :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

if(data != null)
        {
            isPlayingBefore = data.getParcelable("isPlaying");
        }
```

On your `onClick` :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isPlayingBefore)
    {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Already playing song on Activity A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else 
    {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
      }
    }
```

Comment: here isPlayingBefore is of boolean datatype ?

Comment: @Sophie yes its boolean data type

Comment: @Sophie yes, you create a global boolean isPlayingBefore (so all method in the activityB can access it) in activityB and get the result from the activityA